# get list of all discounted items episerver commerce

Tags: episerver

I am trying to display a collection of related items on a page which are at discounted price. I want to know the API call which gets all the discounted items from the database to filter out the related items to the currently displayed item.

Comment: Which products and versions are you using?

Comment: I am using episerver commerce 7.5